# How to change an image during animation with Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm changing an image with webcam frame (or video, no matter)

I want to resize with animation during video plays. (Like youtube expand button but slower)

If I create image with raphael on canvas, image will pause during animation.

Any idea?

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
var camimage = paper.image("bos.jpg",canvasWidth/2,canvasHeight/2,canvasWidth/10,canvasHeight/10);
camimage.animate({transform:"s10"},10000, 'elastic');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ta8mR/14/)**

```
var canvasWidth  = 600,
    canvasHeight = 500;

var paper = new Raphael('canvas_container',canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
var camimage = paper.image("http://davidnaylor.org/temp/firefox-logo-200x200.png",canvasWidth/2,canvasHeight/2,canvasWidth/10,canvasHeight/10);
camimage.animate({transform:"s10"},10000, 'elastic');
```

Let me know, based on the demo, if anything you wanted to do differently.

Comment: So, what is that you need, you need line infinite animation?

Comment: Thanks for answer. No it's not my solution.

I do not have a specific "src". Think there are 100 images and I'm changing src each 50ms.
There is
<img id="camimage"/>
in my Raphael canvas. And changing src with
 $('#camimage').src = NewSrc();

But Raphael canvas only appylies on 1 image, the others stands.

I need to reach Raphael Image object and change it.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you set your first image and it animates, then after that other images just stand and do nothing, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly thats the problem. So summarize, I need to apply Raphael animation to video.